# How to get test FUI9 Overflow component

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

We've created a Tabs component based verbatim on the [TabList with Overflow](https://react.fluentui.dev/?path=/docs/components-tablist--default&globals=storybook_fluentui-react-addon_dir:rtl#with-overflow) example in the fluent docs. The problem we're facing is how to test it's actually overflowing as we'd expect.

I've created [this reduced test](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/35jprc?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrv6kb3m00063b6kx0i26ql2%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B59.3018018063964%252C40.6981981936036%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrv6kb3m00023b6kepd6vskn%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrv6kb3m00033b6k24576xs1%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrv6kb3m00053b6kodgjre8u%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B78.85679447229373%252C21.14320552770627%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clrv6kb3m00023b6kepd6vskn%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrv6kb3m00023b6kepd6vskn%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrv961k202333b6jrkdywn0j%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.codesandbox%252Ftasks.json%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrv961k202333b6jrkdywn0j%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clrv6kb3m00053b6kodgjre8u%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrv6kb3m00053b6kodgjre8u%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522preview%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A4173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrv94v8i020n3b6jk9bpxqu0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrv94v8i020n3b6jk9bpxqu0%2522%257D%252C%2522clrv6kb3m00033b6k24576xs1%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrv6kb3m00033b6k24576xs1%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrvb4fuw00o03b6jwuusq036%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clrvb4fye001je8g10ed0bey4%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrvb4fuw00o03b6jwuusq036%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) as an illustration. Even if we put in a long wait time in the test, the overflow menu button never appears. The only way to trigger the overflow seems to be to explicitly trigger a rerender() on the whole component. Then the overflow menu button will appear.

Does anyone have an suggestions on a "natural" way to get the component to fully render? This only occurs on the tests - not in the actual usages (storybook/app).